# Cron expression parser

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, design-patterns, node.js, interview-questions

#### Problem

Write a command line application or script which parses a cron string and expands each field
to show the times at which it will run.

> ~$ your-program "*/15 0 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find"

```
minute 0 15 30 45
hour 0
day of month 1 15
month 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
day of week 1 2 3 4 5
command /usr/bin/find
```

#### Code

```
/*
 * (minute)(hour)(day of month)(month)(day of week)(command)
 * * = means all possible values
 * - = range of time units
 * , = comma seperated time units
 * / = increments where start is left and right is how much to increment by till max hit
 */

const COLUMN_SIZE = 14;

const fields = [
    "minute",
    "hour",
    "dayOfMonth",
    "month",
    "dayOfWeek",
    "command",
];

const labels = {
    minute: "minute",
    hour: "hour",
    dayOfMonth: "day of month",
    month: "month",
    dayOfWeek: "day of week",
    command: "command",
};

const fieldMap = {
    minute: {
        label: "minute",
        range: [0, 59],
    },
    hour: {
        label: "hour",
        range: [0, 23],
    },
    dayOfMonth: {
        label: "day of month",
        range: [1, 31],
    },
    month: {
        label: "month",
        range: [1, 12],
    },
    dayOfWeek: {
        label: "day of week",
        range: [1, 7],
    },
};

const numberParser = (field, value) => {
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        value = Number(value);
        const [low, high] = fieldMap[field].range;
        if (value < low || value > high) {
            throw new RangeError(`Invalid range.`);
        }
        return "" + value;
    }
};

const commaParser = (field, value, separator = " ") => {
    if (/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/.test(value)) {
        const parts = value.split(",");
        return parts.join(separator);
    }
};

const rangeParser = (field, value) => {
    if (/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/.test(value)) {
        const [low, high] = value.split("-");
        return expand({
            low,
            high,
            range: fieldMap[field].range,
        });
    }
};

const starParser = (field, value) => {
    if (value === "*") {
        const [low, high] = fieldMap[field].range;
        return expand({ low, high });
    }
};

const stepParser = (field, value) => {
    if (value.indexOf("/") > 0) {
        const [start, step] = value.split("/");
        let [low, high] = fieldMap[field].range;
        if (start !== "*") {
            low = Number(start);
        }
        return expand({ low, high, step });
    }
};

const parsers = [
    numberParser,
    stepParser,
    commaParser,
    rangeParser,
    starParser,
];

const expand = ({ low, high, range = [], step = 1 }) => {
    low = Number(low);
    high = Number(high);
    step = Number(step);
    if (low > high) return [];
    const [min, max] = range;
    const result = [];
    let current = low;
    while (current <= high) {
        if ((min != null && current < min) || (max != null && current > max)) {
            throw new RangeError(`Invalid range.`);
        }
        result.push(current);
        current += step;
    }
    return result.join(" ");
};

const formattedOutput = (parsed, padding = COLUMN_SIZE) => {
    const output = [];
    for (let field of fields) {
        output.push(`${labels[field].padEnd(padding)} ${parsed[field]}`);
    }
    return output.join("\n");
};

const parse = (str) => {
    if (typeof str !== "string") {
        throw new TypeError("Expected a string");
    }
    str = str.trim();
    const parts = str.split(" ");
    if (parts.length !== 6) {
        throw new TypeError("Invalid cron format");
    }
    const command = parts[5];
    const result = Object.create(null);
    for (let idx = 0; idx < fields.length; idx++) {
        const field = fields[idx];
        let value = field === "command" ? command : "-";
        if (field === "command") {
            result[field] = value;
            continue;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < parsers.length; i++) {
            const parser = parsers[i];
            const result = parser(field, parts[idx]);
            if (result != null) {
                value = result;
                break;
            }
        }
        result[field] = value;
    }
    return result;
};

module.exports = {
    parse,
    formattedOutput,
};
```

#### Test

```
const test = require("ava");
const { parse } = require("./lib");

test("throws", (t) => {
    let error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse();
        },
        { instanceOf: TypeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Expected a string");

    error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse(1234);
        },
        { instanceOf: TypeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Expected a string");

    error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse("* * * *");
        },
        { instanceOf: TypeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Invalid cron format");
});

test("parse", (t) => {
    const { minute, hour, month, dayOfMonth, dayOfWeek, command } = parse(
        "*/15 0 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find"
    );

    t.is(month, "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12");
    t.is(dayOfMonth, "1 15");
    t.is(dayOfWeek, "1 2 3 4 5");
    t.is(command, "/usr/bin/find");

    t.is(parse("*/15 0 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").minute, "0 15 30 45");
    t.is(parse("1/30 0 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").minute, "1 31");

    t.is(parse("1/30 1 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").hour, "1");
    t.is(parse("1/30 1-3 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").hour, "1 2 3");

    t.is(parse("1/30 0 1,15,16 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").dayOfMonth, "1 15 16");
    t.is(parse("1/30 0 21 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").dayOfMonth, "21");

    t.is(
        parse("1/30 1 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").month,
        "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12"
    );
    t.is(parse("1/30 1 1,15 */2 1-5 /usr/bin/find").month, "1 3 5 7 9 11");

    t.is(parse("1/30 0 1,15 * 1-7 /usr/bin/find").dayOfWeek, "1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
    t.is(parse("1-6 0 1,15 * 1-7 /usr/bin/find").minute, "1 2 3 4 5 6");

    t.is(parse("1/30 1 1,15 * 1-5 /usr/bin/find").command, "/usr/bin/find");
});

test("throws on invalid input range", (t) => {
    let error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse("1-60 0 1,15 * 1-7 /usr/bin/find");
        },
        { instanceOf: RangeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Invalid range.");

    error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse("1-59 24 1,15 * 1-8 /usr/bin/find");
        },
        { instanceOf: RangeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Invalid range.");

    error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse("1-59 23 1,15 * 1-8 /usr/bin/find");
        },
        { instanceOf: RangeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Invalid range.");

    error = t.throws(
        () => {
            parse("1-59 -23 1,15 * 1-7 /usr/bin/find");
        },
        { instanceOf: RangeError }
    );
    t.is(error.message, "Invalid range.");
});
```

#### Questions

1. I would like to understand how can I make this code production ready?
2. How can I do to make sure it runs on multiple platform?
3. Are the test cases good enough?

Comment: Why multiple parsers? They should parse every level of expression by invoke each other. For example, how would you handle `3,4-6,8-20/2,30/5 * * * *` and even `*,3,4 * * * *`? Why parser return an string instead of array of integers? May command includes spaces?